# HTML5 video source is not directing

Tags: html, video, mp4

I have a project of mine, simple video player in HTML, however, the *src* is not working correctly, if I copy and paste the *src* into browser URL, the video comes up, but not on my site. WHY? This is also a shared drive on my network.

```
    <video  width="1280" height="720" controls>
            <source src="file:////192.168.***.***/chuck1/chucke.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

The video comes up with "no video support".

Comment: loading local files is not foreseen in the HTML5 video standard, have you tried to load the same video from a webserver? ...just place it where your website is for start and try to load it using a http:// url instead of file://

Comment: I have tried doing what you said, it did not work. I also tried just typing "file:////192.168.***.***/chuck1/chucke.mp4" in my chrome URL, then it worked, but I can't seem to get the video on my website.

Comment: Device, OS, Browsers? What mime type did your webserver serve when accessing the file via http://?